# Filter an array inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, data-structures

i hope you cans help me with this... I'm using AngularJS =>

before sending a query in MongoDB, I have to filter an array, all the values come from ng-model, and it's created when the form is submitted, but before sending the query, i have to filter the array so I can discard undefined values,
The structure is the following:

```
this.permision = [
    {
       title: 'Archivo',
       submenu: [this.menu.productCatalog, this.menu.providers]
    },
    {
       title: 'Usuarios',
       submenu: [this.menu.users, this.menu.roles]
    },
    {
        title: 'Presupuesto',
        submenu: [this.menu.invoiceLog, this.menu.requestLog, 
        this.menu.creditLog, this.menu.reportLog]
    },
    {
         title: 'Requerimientos',
         submenu: [this.menu.dps1f1, this.menu.catalog,
         this.menu.consolidate, this.menu.expenses,
         this.menu.purchaseGeneration, 
         this.menu.purchaseTracking,
         this.menu.circuits]
   },
   {
         title: 'Operaciones',
         submenu: [this.menu.account, this.menu.loadPay, 
         this.menu.accountStatus]
   },
   {
         title: 'Graficos',
         submenu: [this.menu.importFile]
   },
   {
         title: 'Cuenta Corriente',
         submenu: [this.menu.credit, this.menu.rates]
   },
];
```

How can I access the submenu array and filter it before sending the query?

This is the answer i'm getting when i send the query:

```
{submenu:["DPS1F1", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined] title : "Requerimientos"}
```

so, all the undefined values have to be removed, but they're in a deep position inside of the array.

`Array.filter()` doesn't seems to work and if I try to get `indexOf()` to use `Splice()` it doesn't seems to to work either? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should add what you have tried in terms of filtering so far. Also you may need to clarify "undefined values" and what those would look like. Thanks!

Comment: When I log the console for a response, this is what i get: 
submenu
:
(7) ["DPS1F1", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
title
:
"Requerimientos" , so this undefined values are the ones i want to remove before sending the query. thanks!

Comment: You'd want to update the question with the code you are using to achieve that result so far. That will help others answer the question. That being said, it looks like you're almost there.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this approach:

```
this.permision = this.permision.map(function(permision) {
  return {
    title: permission.title,
    submenu: permission.submenu.filter(Boolean)
  };
});
```

What this does is transform each entry of `this.permision` using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) into an object that has the same title but the difference is that it filters ([Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) the `submenu` array. The filter function predicate is the [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) function. Basically, each item of the `submenu` array is going to be coerced/evaluated to see if it's [truthy or falsy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `underscorejs`.

```
this.permision.map((e)=>{
   e.submenu = _.compact(e.submenu);
});
```

**compact** _.compact(list) 
Returns a copy of the list with all falsy values removed. In JavaScript, false, null, 0, "", undefined and NaN are all falsy.

[underscorejs](https://underscorejs.org/#compact)